# C++: using select()

Tags: c++, sockets, select

I am building a client that can recieve information from the server and from the user (`stdin`), so I am using select to monitor both. What happens is that is a keyboard input is monitored the I send a message to the client and get one back, no problem. But when the server send a message nothing happens, and I don't know why. Is using `select()` the proper way to do so?

Here's my code:

```
void readSocket(fd_set tempfd) {
    const char * tweet, * inMessage;
    if (FD_ISSET(srverfd,&tempfd)) {
        inMessage = getMessage();
        printSystemMessages(inMessage);
    }

    if (FD_ISSET(STDIN_FILENO,&tempfd)) {
        tweet = getUserTweet();
        sendMessage(tweet);
        inMessage = getMessage();
        if (strcmp(inMessage,OK) != 0) {
            printSystemMessages(inMessage);
        }
        if (strcmp(inMessage,EXIT) == 0) {
            return;
        }
    }
    return;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[] ){
    int value;
    bool clientON = false;
    fd_set tempfd;

    if(establishConnection(argv[2],argv[3])){
        cerr << "usage: failed to make connection" << endl << "exiting..." << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    cout << "Connected successfully" << endl;
    sendMessage("CONNECT "+clientName); //Connect
    if(strcmp(getMessage(),OK) == 0){
        build_select_list();
        printSystemMessages("Welcome!");
        clientON = true;
        cout<< man <<endl;
    }
    while(clientON){
        tempfd = inputFdSet;
        printTweetFormat("TweetMy:");

        value = select(maxSock, &tempfd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        if (value < 0) {
            perror("select");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if (value == 0) {
            continue;
        }
        else {
            readSocket(tempfd);
        }
    }
    close(srverfd);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you can refer to http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/ for usage of select.

Comment: You have 2 main functions above - you could really clean this up to make things clearer and would then be more likely to get an answer

Comment: @curiousbill - I read it several times, couldn't find an answer.

Comment: Your example doesn't even compile... how can anybody find an error if there is no code.

Comment: Clients usually dont receive from servers unless they request data. Are you saying that the server is writing to the client without the client requesting? Servers usually do this using listen() and accept(). Clients usually read only when they are expecting a reply to a request.

Comment: @EitanT That is not what I was trying to say. I am simply suggesting that possibly if there is a conceptual error and without reliable code examples to go on he is perhaps not listening for data in the correct way - ie client not receiving data because its not listening for it. I agree it is guesswork - just trying to help

Comment: @mathematician well it's obvious that the client is trying to listen to _something_ if it uses `select()`, no?

Comment: @EitanT - precisely - a select() without timeout listening for something thats not being sent

Comment: @yotamoo This look awfully like your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11016045/server-does-not-respond-to-new-clients-using-select-cpp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you - pass maxSock+1 instead of maxSock to your select() call;

From the man page on select()

```
     nfds  is the highest-numbered file descriptor in any of the three sets,
      plus 1.
```

Comment: That's a very good point. However, since `maxSock` is not defined anywhere in this code snippet, you can never know if it already includes the `+ 1` or not :)

Comment: @EitanT - Indeed - that is why i said "This *might* help" :)